# How store different data type in list c#

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a collection of data

```
id     int
Name   string
```

so i want to store this data in a list.
i am writing query

```
List<int> storedata = tabledata.Select(p => new {p.id, p.Name});
```

but i am getting error. so what is the right way to do this.

Comment: Always mention errors including message and stacktrace if you ask something at stackoverflow

Comment: `but i am getting error.` In these situations, it is super helpful if you show us the **details** of the error.

Comment: Also, don't show pseudo-code that doesn't even compile for other reasons than the mentioned error. In this case you have written code here from memory instead of simply copy&pasting from your code file. I have "fixed" several typos.

Comment: thanks for this, next time i will take care

Answer (score 4):

I suggest using `var` and `.ToList()` if you want a *list* of *anonymous type*:

```
var store = tabledata
  .Select(p => new {id = p.id, name = p.Name}) // Anonymous type
  .ToList();                                   // list of anonymous type's items
```

Let .Net infer (`var`) the type for you. However, taking your data into account (`id` and `name`), you may want to store the data as a *dictionary*, not *list*:

```
Dictionary<int, string> data = tabledata
  .ToDictionary(p => p.id, p => p.Name);

...

string name123 = data[123]; // let's have a value that corresponds to id = 123

if (data.ContainsKey(789)) {
  // do we have id = 789? 
}

if (data.TryGetValue(456, out var name456)) { // C# 7.0 Syntax
  // If we have id = 456, return corresponding value into name456
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an error because the return value of `Select(p => new {p.id, p.Name})` is not `List<int>` but it is of an IEnumerable of `anonymous` type which is specified by the compiler and cannot be known when you write the code.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple compiler errors involved in this line:

```
List<int> storedata = tabledata.Select(p => new {p.id, p.Name});
```

First, the Select() method returns an IEnumerable. Trying to store the result of a Select operation into a List just won't work.

Second, the type returned by the Select operation is a problem. The body of the selection...

```
p => new {p.id, p.Name}
```

... returns an anonymous type. The storedata variable you've defined as List expects to be populated with simple integers.

Not that I'm recommending it but the following would compile, for example:
`IEnumerable<object> storedata = tabledata.Select(p => new {p.id, p.Name});`

Comment: thanks for reply. but i want result in the form of list